# (vue.js) When clicking on an image, I want to call a modal for each image

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, popup, v-for

When clicking on an image, I want to call a modal for each image.

There are currently 3 images and clicking on the image brings up a modal without content.

**Here is what my directory looks like:**

components

ㅡcommon

ㅡㅡModal.vue

ㅡContent.vue

ㅡDetail.vue

**App.vue**

```html
data () {
    return {
      imgItems: [
        {
          thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/aa.jpg'),
          description: 'aa'
        },
        {
          thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/bb.jpg'),
          description: 'bb'
        },
        {
          thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/cc.jpg'),
          description: 'cc'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Content.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <img :src="item.thumbnail" class="gallery-image">
          {{ item.thumbnail }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    items: { type: Array, default: () => [] }
  }
}
</script>
```

I hope you can help me. thanks!XD

Comment: you should close img tag  `/>` like `<img :src="item.thumbnail" class="gallery-image"/>`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It's corrected. Thank you for the comment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image, add an v-on click event at the tags, linking it to a method:

```
 <img :src="item.thumbnail" class="gallery-image" @click="modalHandler">
```

you can also do this:

```
<img :src="item.thumbnail" class="gallery-image" @click="showModal = !showModal">
```

Then, you must add some new data to your data classes, to toggle the modal:

```
data () {
return {
  imgItems: [
    {
      thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/aa.jpg'),
      description: 'aa'
    },
    {
      thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/bb.jpg'),
      description: 'bb'
    },
    {
      thumbnail: require('./assets/imgs/cc.jpg'),
      description: 'cc'
    }
  ],
  showModal: false
}
```

}

Then, at your HTML page, go to the MODAL and use a v-if to only render it when showModal = true

```
<modal v-if="showModal">
```

Comment: Click events and data were added. Thanks for the feedback. :D